# Post-build script path not getting logged in build log

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I have created a build definition using ReleaseTfvcTemplate.12.xaml.
 In "Post-build script path" i am invoking a powershell script file.
 But i could not see the execution of this powershell shell in build log

Answer (score 1):

There might be different reasons why you don't see any output from the post-build script.

1. Depending on the source location of your script file, you might need
   to include it in the "Source Settings" in your build definition (it
   should be listed as another working folder if it is different as the
   location of your solution file(s) and this path excludes the
   script file).
2. When using Powershell's Write- functions, only these will show up in the output log:

   - Write-Host
   - Write-Output
   - Write-Warning
   - Write-Error
3. Make sure you check the execution time of the your build event: "Run optional script after MSBuild". If it's greater than 00:00:00, the script has been running. It's normal that you don't see any logging in the build log you have in Visual Studio. Open the Log files instead (there can be multiple xml files) or view the Diagnostics information on Visual Studio Online (Actions => Open in browser) (it uses the xsl to present you a cleaner html layout).